# Play alarm sound just once

Tags: android

I have a working alarm app, but wanted to add a feature where the user gets the choice between "Play alarm continuously till acknowledged" and "play alarm sound once".

I then looked at my alrm ringing code expecting to see some kind of "repeat" flag which I could optionally remove - but there was none. So how do I play the alarm sound just once?

My existing code looks like this:

```
private void playSound(Context context, Uri alert) 
{
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try 
    {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, alert);
        final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0)
        {
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // oops!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually in each alarm sound there is a FLAG named ANDROID_LOOP which force your sound to loop. Unfortunatly you can't change that flag even using MediaPlayer.setLooping(false).
But you still can manually stop your player after a certain time. For example getDuration will give  you the length of your sound.

```
int duration = mMediaPlayer.getDuration();

Runnable stopSoundRunnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                  mMediaPlayer.stop();
            }
        };

mSoundHanlder.postDelayed(stopSoundRunnable, duration);
```